# How do I rename fields in the outputs of a Mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to transform this SQL query (**my objective is to transform description into desc**) in a mongoose function for MongoDB.

```
select description as desc from book
```

How do I fix this function?

```
book.find({})
    .lean()
    .exec(function(err, recs) {
       if (err) {
           console.warn(err)
       } else {
           console.log(recs);
     });
```

Comment: `db.book.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "desc": "$description"
    }}
])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try projection in `aggregation` pipeline

```
book.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,  
            'desc': '$description' //aliasing 
        }
    }
], function (err, recs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(recs);
    }
});
```

Read more about `aggregation` from [here](http://excellencenodejsblog.com/mongoose-aggregation-count-group-match-project/)

Comment: It works, thank you. Where do I put the 'where' ({_id: 0}) object? And how do I rename a object property in the record? For example `{_id: 0, title: 'Hello world', author: {name: 'John', surname: 'Cena'}}` **I want to rename author.name as name.**

Comment: `{_id: 0, title: 'Hello world', author: {name: 'John', surname: 'Cena', nationality: 273}}` **And also I want to extract author.nationality.name as nationality that is the ID of a record in another collection.**

Comment: for `author.name` you can write `name: '$author.name'` in `$project` fields

Comment: And the nationality? How do I extract the field 'name' and rename it 'nationality'?

Comment: Same as before with `nationality: $author.nationality.name` in `$project`